# How to change text color with elementor or theme's php files in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, customization, elementor

I am using a theme in wordpress with elementor and i tried to find the header nav bar's type styles but i couldn't find it in elementor. After that, i searched a little in the theme's files and i found something like that;

wdes-menu-navbar ul.default-drop > li > a {
color: ;

and when i search for 'color-header-menu-clr' in PhpStorm, i found this;

```
'package-options'      =>array(
                    array(
                        'id'              => 'color-header-menu-clr',
                        'type'            => 'color',
                        'title'           => esc_html__('Link Color','phox'),
                        'desc'            => esc_html__('', 'phox'),
                        'note'            => esc_html__('', 'phox'),
                        'class'           => 'block-function-c',
                        'def'             => '#ced4d9'
```

The main problem is, #ced4d9 is not working right now. The website takes it as #444444. I searched it but i found so much things. How can i change it it on elementor or php files?

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the end of `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/style.css` file :

```
#color-header-menu-clr{
   color: #ced4d9 !important;
}
```